# PrivateRoute not working in reactjs react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am completely stuck when integrating `PrivateRoute` HOC in my react.js project.

Here is my **route** file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from "../view/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Login from "../view/Login/Login";
import Admin from "../view/UserManagement/Admin";
import cookie from 'react-cookies'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthed = cookie.load('token')
  console.log(isAuthed, 'dddddddddddddddddddd')
  return (
    <Route {...rest} exact
      render = {(props) => (
        isAuthed ? (
          <div>
            {React.createElement(component, props)}
          </div>
        ) :
        (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      )}
    />
  )
}

class MainPanel extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ direction: direction }}> 
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/AdminManagement" component={Admin} />
           </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withNamespaces('common') (MainPanel);
```

I am totally break my head with this but didn't get rid out of that issue. Why my console inside the `PrivateRoute` doesn't show the values

Is there any issue with the react and react-router-dom versions

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You mean when you go to either Dashboard or Admin component, the console log does not print anything?

Comment: Did you try to access the Dashboard or Admin page to activate this `console.log` ?

Comment: @dnp1204 yes you are right

Comment: @Weedoze yes but it doesn't console anything

Comment: Do you get any error in the console

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri No sir there is no error in the console.

Comment: Could you prepare a demo which reproduces your error

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Is there any place where I can create a fiddle ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Please have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/1zx57kl594

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188201/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-profer).

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54626313/10761855

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PrivateRoute` component that you have is correct, You however only need to re-order your `Routes` for them to work correctly. `/AdminManagement` route should come before `/` since Switch renders the first matching Route and a `Route path` will also match its prefix path

```
class MainPanel extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ direction: direction }}> 
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <PrivateRoute path="/AdminManagement" component={Admin} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard} />
           </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withNamespaces('common') (MainPanel);
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3pjopj70p)**

Comment: Thank you... But It works partially. It is redirecting me to `/login` always. Why so?

Comment: @Profer because the localStorage must be set on login otherwise it will never work

Comment: @Profer, were you able to solve the above issue with the above answer.

Comment: @Profer, not worrying about award. I didn't receive any response from you after my last comment, thats the reason I wanted to confirm

Comment: *didn't receive any response from you after my last comment* Apologies for that

Comment: `/AdminManagement route should come before / since Switch renders the first matching Route and a Route path will also match its prefix path`, so /AdmingManagement also matches `/` and hence Admin won't be rendered but Dashboard will always render in your case

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I handle my private routes, maybe it will help you also. I have `protectedRoutes` as an array with the routes. you can fit them as you like.

```html
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login', exact: true, name: 'Login', component: Login,
  },
];

const protectedRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/admin', exact: true, name: 'Admin', component: Admin,
  },
];
```

```html
<Switch>

    {routes.map((route, idx) => (route.component ? (
         <Route
             key={idx}
             path={route.path}
             exact={route.exact}
             name={route.name}
             render={props => (
             <route.component {...props} />
             )}
          />
            )
     : (null)))}

     {protectedRoutes.map((route, idx) => (route.component ? (
          <Route
              key={idx}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
              name={route.name}
              render={props => (
                isAuth
                  ? <route.component {...props} />
                  : <Redirect to="/login" />
                )}
           />
       )
       : (null)))}
        
</Switch>
```

LE: added full example based on the original code

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from '../view/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Login from '../view/Login/Login';
import Admin from '../view/UserManagement/Admin';
import cookie from 'react-cookies';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login', exact: true, name: 'Login', component: Login,
  },
];

const protectedRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard,
  },
  {
    path: '/AdminManagement', exact: true, name: 'Admin', component: Admin,
  },
];

class MainPanel extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuthed: cookie.load('token'),
    },
  };

  render() {
    const { isAuthed } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ direction: direction }}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            {routes.map((route, idx) => (route.component ? (
                <Route
                  key={idx}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  name={route.name}
                  render={props => (
                    <route.component {...props} />
                  )}
                />
              )
              : (null)))}

            {protectedRoutes.map((route, idx) => (route.component ? (
                <Route
                  key={idx}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  name={route.name}
                  render={props => (
                    isAuth
                      ? <route.component {...props} />
                      : <Redirect to="/login" />
                  )}
                />
              )
              : (null)))}
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withNamespaces('common')(MainPanel);
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question

Comment: It's just a different approach to the issue in hand. I agree that it does not answer the question but it may help to achieve the desired result. If not I will gladly remove the answer

Answer (score 2):

try change library to `react-cookie`;

```
let PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, cookies, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      cookies.get("name") ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/015k0jl0ql

Comment: This does not answer OP's question + OP is already using react-cookie library

Comment: Why not? if you change lib you can see data in console.log from cookie

Comment: OP needs a solution with the current libraries. Another library is not necessary to fix his problem.